# UIImage not being read properly after entering foreground

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I am in a real rough situation trying to squish this bug.
In a perfect world, I can press a "success" button, it plays a sound and vibrates, and changes the image in a UIImageView. This works perfectly until I press the home button and reopen the app. This glitch ALWAYS occurs.

Here is the relevant code:

```
@IBAction func Success(_ sender: Any) {
    var boxNum = 1
    generator.impactOccurred()
    if "" == defaults.value(forKey: "frequency") as? String{
        //One of 2 frequencies. It doesn't make a difference, however because the glitch always happens.
        playVictorySound()
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        for box in Boxes{
            if box.image == UIImage(named:"blank.png"){
                if "" == defaults.value(forKey: mode) as? String{
                    formatter.dateFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy"
                    let activeDate = Date()
                    defaults.set(Date(), forKey: "dateLast")
                    print(activeDate)
                    }
                box.image = UIImage(named:"Arm.png")
                defaults.set("Active", forKey: "boxState" + String(boxNum))
                print("Active set for" + " boxState" + String(boxNum))
                if "" == defaults.value(forKey: "mode") as? String{
                    successButton.isHidden = true
                    failButton.isHidden = true
                }
                break
            }
            else{
                boxNum = boxNum + 1
                print ("Added 1 to" + String(boxNum))
                
            }
        }
    }
```

NOTE: This section has the user defaults that are set during the button press.

When the app is re-opened, the success button plays a sound (which is desired), and vibrates the phone (also desired), but the images do not update. In fact, the console prints a series of the else case.

> Added 1 to38
>
> Added 1 to39
>
> Added 1 to40

Etc etc.

When any other modes or frequencies are set, the glitch also occurs. I am focused on fixing this case because I think I will be able to fix the others as well.
Is there some underlying reason causing this? I believe it may be because either something isn't being kept in memory, but I cannot figure out why. Thank you very much.

EDIT: Ok, I set the "blank" image to a selfie, and the app loads up "blank.png" for every square. There seems to be something wrong with another part of the code above.

I added print statements to help a bit and the if statement is the part that is failing, however, the ImageViews all have blank.png set as their image.

Comment: Don't use `value(forKey:)`. UserDefaults has a method exactly for loading string values from it called `string(forKey:)` Btw it is Swift naming convention to name your methods and variables starting with a lowercase letter.

Comment: You've already explained what's going on. You are saying `for box in Boxes { if box.image == UIImage(named:"blank.png") ` and the `if` is failing. We don't know how Boxes is created but clearly at app launch it isn't ready yet. Use the debugger to see what Boxes is at this point.

Comment: And why are you setting a date format just to set the date to user defaults? It is pointless

Comment: `if "" == defaults.value(forKey: "mode") as? String` also doesn't make any sense. if you would like to check if there isn't a value in your user defaults check if `object(forKey:) == nil`

Comment: Leo Dabus im using it for another part of the app. I could also use the nil method but I use a nil as a value and it makes the code easier to read. Ill fix all the variables to make it nicer too. Thank you! Is it faster to use String(forKey:)?

Comment: Matt, the boxes is a collection of 49 uiimageviews. How would I use the debugger to do this?

Comment: It is not faster. It is the correct way. And the type return isn't optional Any `Any?`. It is optional String `String?` so you don't need to cast it to String.

Comment: If you are saving an empty string to user defaults (you shouldn't), you can load the string and check if it is empty. `if let mode = defaults.string(forKey: "mode"), mode.isEmpty {`

Comment: It is a collection of 49 image views, but at the time your code runs at app launch, _none_ of those image views evidently has _blank.png_ as its image. If any of them did, you'd fall into the `if` side of your condition. But you don't. Simple logic.

Comment: @matt , I set the blank.png to an image of myself, so I could visually see if the ImageView is setting the image correctly, and it does! The if statement seems to not register that the image is indeed set as blank.png.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my issue using a workaround. I stopped checking the content of the UIImageView (Which for some reason didn't work), and instead used UserDefaults to see what the image should be.

I set a value in UserDefaults for all the possible images, and then check what the value of the default is.